# How do I stop R studio from marking open scripts as unsaved?

Tags: r, user-interface, statistics, rstudio, workflow

If an R script is open in a tab it often changes it status from saved to unsaved even if no changes were made.

saved:

[image: image of unsaved tab]

unsaved:

[image: image of unsaved tab]

This makes it difficult to keep track of which scripts were actually changed.
Why is R studio behaving like this and what can I do to stop it?

Comment: usually something IS changed whenever this happens. the changes may however occur outside the script - for example if you saved the script to a usb stick and removed said stick, rstudio will change the status to unsaved.

Comment: I thought about this. But if I check for changes via Git it does not find any. It only seems to be recognized or maybe even caused by R studio.

Comment: did you test it? maybe by creating a simple script saved to your desktop and letting it sit. if it still changes from saved to not saved, asking the devs may be warranted.